# H spaces and Quillen's rational homotopy theorem

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Quillen's theorem gives an equivalence
$$\text{Spaces}/\text{rational homotopy equivalance} \ \stackrel{\sim}{\longleftrightarrow} \ \text{dgla's}/\text{quasi-isomorphism}$$
such that if space $X$ corresponds to dgla $L$, then $H^*(L)=\pi_*(X;\mathbf{Q})$ as vector spaces.

> **Question:** Is there an $H$-space with associated dgla $\mathfrak{g}[-1]\oplus\mathfrak{g}[-2]\oplus\cdots$, i.e. with finite dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ in positive degrees and zero differential? More generally, can one describe which dgla's the $H$-spaces correspond to?

(I am asking this because I would like to know if there is an $H$-space $X$ with $H^*(X)=\text{U}(t\mathfrak{g}[t])$ as vector spaces).

Comment: I believe that every H-space is rationally the product of EM-spaces (at least this holds for loop spaces), so you do not need to invoke Quillen to understand their rational homotopy types.

Comment: @JensReinhold So does this mean that there is or is not an H space with dgla as above (and Samelson product the associated product on the Lie algebra)?